# Falling images that can be pressed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d

In my cocos2d app I am trying to make images fall from the top of the screen and detect when they are pressed. I am having a hard time. Can anyone help me achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have implemented some [touch delegate](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3atouchdelegates) you can easely tell if you touched your sprite or not using bounding boxes, doing something like:

```
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchPoint, [sprite boundingBox])){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do a language and platform independent approach here.

All images should be represented as rectangles. Rectangles are usually just 4 elements long arrays that look like this: `[x, y, width, height]`.

`x` and `y` represent the position of the image. If you want the image to have a falling effect, ie to move downwards, they you will want to increase the `y` coordinate gradually (the `y` axis increases "downwards" in computer graphics, remember that).

The `width` and `height`, obviously, represent the dimensions of the image.

A **click** can be represented by two numbers, just the `x` and `y`, as it is actually just a point in space, it doesn't have any dimensions.

Now, your problem is essentially checking whether the click happened *inside* the image. How do you do that?

Well, like this:

```
//xc = click x
//yc = click y
//rect = [x, y, width, height]

if (xc >= rect[0] && xc <= rect[0] + rect[2] && yc >= rect[1] && yc <= rect[1] + rect[3])
{
    //Click happened.
}
else
{
    //The click was outside of this particular image.
}
```

If you don't understand the code, tell me what is bothering you in a comment and I will explain further.

Comment: This is cocos2d for iOS. I am trying to have images fall from the top of the screen and the user of the application is trying to press them.